# Characterizing functions that satisfy the reflection $f(z)f(-z)=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, meromorphic-functions

**Context:**
During a mathematical discussion with a good friend, I was brought to think about the functional equation $q(t)q(1-t) = 1$ for $q$ with some regularity. (To be honest the exact context doesn't really matter, since I am not trying to solve the original problem that this stemmed from). Upon brainstorming a few solutions ($exp(t-1/2)$, $\Gamma(t)\sqrt{\sin \pi t}$ up to a constant)), I came to realize that the solutions are plentiful. By reparameterizing the functions and choosing the regularity to be meromorphic (motivated by the fact that all the pretty solutions were meromorphic), I set myself to the following challenge:

*Characterise/Classify all the functions $f \in \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{D})$ which satisfy the reflection $f(z)f(-z)=1$*

My attempt goes as follows:

Denote by $G$ the set of such functions. After some verifications, it becomes clear that $G$ is actually a group with respect to the operation of pointwise multiplication* of functions (*one has to take care of removable singularities). Moreover, define the function
\begin{align} K : \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{D})  &\to \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{D}) \\\\ f(z) &\to K(f)(z) = f(z)/f(-z) \end{align}

Easy computations show the following three facts:

1. The image of $K$ is inside $G$, ie $Im(K) \subset G$
2. K is in fact a morphism of groups with respect to multiplication
3. The kernel of $K$ is the subgroup of **even** meromorphic functions on the unit disk, let's call it $\mathcal{E}(\mathbb{D})$

Now using the first isomorphism theorem, one obtains the following isomorphism of groups:
$\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{D})/\mathcal{E}(\mathbb{D}) \cong Im(K)$

Obviously for my purpose, I'd like $K$ to be onto $G$, in other words, I want to be able to express every $g \in G$ as $g(z) = f(z) / f(-z)$ for some meromorphic $f$, obtaining the isomorphism of groups: $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{D})/\mathcal{E}(\mathbb{D}) \cong G$

There is some non formal evidence for that being the case, but I'd like to formalize it. The path I took was the following:
if $g \in G$ is without any zeroes, then it is also without poles, so there exists a holomorphic branch of its square root on $\mathbb{D}$. Then $f(z) = \sqrt{g(z)}$ satisfies the following:

$f(z) / f(-z) = \sqrt{g(z)}/\sqrt{g(-z)} = g(z) / (\sqrt{g(z)}\sqrt{g(-z)})$, where the last denominators square is equal to one (since $g \in G$), so that it itself must be equal to one (if one takes the correct branch?). Thus any $g\in G$ without zeroes can be expressed as $f(z) / f(-z)$ for some meromorphic $f$.

To tackle the case where $g$ is allowed to be zero, we'll show a little lemma:

**lemma:**
$g\in G$ admits the desired decomposition iff there exists an even meromorphic $e$ such that there exists a meromorphic branch of  $\sqrt{e(z)g(z)}$

proof: if such an $e$ exists then one can set $f(z) = \sqrt{e(z)g(z)}$ and redo the previous computations. For the converse, consider $f^2(z) / g(z) \blacksquare$

In our case, the poles and zeros of $g$ come in pairs: if $z$ is a zero of order $n$ then $-z$ is a pole of order $n$ and vice versa. By multiplying by our magic $e$, we want to make all the orders of the zeroes/poles even, then $eg$ will admit a square root. An easy example is if $g$ has a finite number of zeroes of odd order, say $\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n$: one considers: $e(z) = \prod_k (z^2 - \alpha_k^2)$. This finite product is an even function that has simple zeroes at all the points where $g$ has an odd ordered zero, thus $eg$ will only have even ordered zeroes and hence admits a square root. (and obviously the problem of the poles is also taken care of, since for any odd ordered pole $-\alpha_k$, the product $eg$ will have the pole's order decreased by one, giving an even ordered pole)

This is where the problem comes: what if $g$ has an infinite number of odd ordered zeroes? In that case the aforementioned product has no reason to converge (that I'm aware of). Is there a workaround with more well chosen functions than $(z^2 - \alpha^2)$ to make the infinite product converge? Or is this approach just not good enough to obtain the full result?

Comment: if $f(z)$ is even $f(z)=f(-z)$ then $f(z)f(-z)=(f(z))^2=1$ so if $f(z)$ real-valued and non-constant it don't going be an even function (if exist), right?

Comment: For any at most countable set $z_n$ that is finite or satisfies $|z_n| \to 1$ which is disjoint from the set $-z_n$, for any multiplicity $k_n \ge 1$, for any odd power series $g(z)= a_1z+a_3z^3+..$ and for $m=0,1$ one can construct an $f$ as above as $(-1)^mh(z)/h(-z) \times e^{g(z)}$ where $h$ is any analytic function in the disc with zeroes precisely at $z_n$ with multiplicity $k_n$ (which exists by general theory) and any $f$ is given as such but of course non uniquely; if the zeroes satisfy "good" properties one can find canonical such representations; this implies the OP conjecture

Comment: @Conrad this ties into another approach I took with Blaschke products: turns out $B_a(z)B_{-1/\bar{a}}(z) \in G$  and has a simple zero at $a$ and a simple pole at $-a$. Thus for any $f$, the product $f(z) / \prod_\alpha B_\alpha(z)B_{-1/\bar{\alpha}}(z)$ can be made to have no zeroes by taking the product over its zeroes, which then admits an odd branch of log (up to  $+2\pi i$). however I ran into the same problem: the product converges iff $\sum (1-|\alpha|) < \infty$ (from wikipedia)
So do you mind telling me more about the general theory that gives the existence of such $h$?

Comment: @Joako yes, even functions that satisfy the condition must be constant. This ties into the idea that $G$ is obtained from $\mathcal{M(}\mathbb{D})$ by quotienting out the even functions

Comment: Let $U$ a domain not full plane (as we know how to construct entire functions with prescribed zeroes) and let $z_n$ a sequence in $U$ with no limit points in $U$ where we repeat each $z_n$ given multiplicity $k_n$ and reindex ; then we can pick $q_n$ in the exterior of $U$ (or on boundary) st $z_n-q_n \to 0$. Then if we pick $r_n$ large enough so $\sum |R(z_n-q_n)|^{r_n+1}<\infty$ for all $R>0$ the modified Weierstrass product with terms $E_{r_n}(\frac{z_n-q_n}{z-q_n})$ converges normally in $U$ to a holomorphic function with zeroes precisely at $z_n$ (as many as how many times $z_n$ appears)

Comment: In the above we can assume that the limit points are bounded by picking a point $a$ (which can be in $U$) away from the closure of the zero set and inverting $U$ with $1/(z-a)$ etc as even if $a$ in $U$ the modified Weierstrass is bounded at infinity so extends analytically there (or we can split the zero set into a part with bounded closure and a part that goes to infinity and apply the usual Weierstrass construction for the latter which gives an entire function)

Comment: Thanks @Conrad I've got all the pieces to make my approach work now. Is it customary in these cases that I answer my own question by referencing your comments?

Comment: That's fine - your supported guess is correct though not that illuminating in a sense (and applies to other domains though usually simple connectedness is needed for good answers) but if you impose additional conditions like the Blaschke one for zeroes you have good explicit examples